# Why is my SQL statement with OFFSET/FETCH not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server, and in the table `Purchase` I have about 50 records.
I am trying to fetch the first 20 (0-20), then 20-40, and finally the last 10.

The SQL I have is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Purchase
WHERE dataOK = 'OK'
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

SELECT *
FROM Purchase
WHERE dataOK = 'OK'
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC
OFFSET 19 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

SELECT *
FROM Purchase
WHERE dataOK = 'OK'
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC
OFFSET 39 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

The first two commands are returning exactly the same records.
Why are they not showing two different sets of result?

EDIT: I understand that `XX` in `FETCH XX` is the number of rows to be returned. But my SQL server is returning exactly same result for the above first 2 commands.

Comment: Hint:  `FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: But why is it not "OFFSET"-ing at all? The first 2 commands are returning the same result.

Comment: I was thinking OFFSET 20 means skip the first 20 records from whatever is selected, and then FETCH will get the data from there.

Comment: does the 3th command returns different rows or no rows at all ?

Comment: The 3rd one returns a different set of results. Whatever is remaining in the table is selected. This one seems to be okay. But still the first two are returning the same result set. All records are unique, so they should return completely different sets of records though... but they are returninig the same set.

Comment: Are the dates unique?

Comment: yes each record has a unique ID, so I can tell if the returned sets of data are the same or not. The first and second commands are returning exactly same data set, and I am so confused.

Comment: I did not ask you if the records have a unique ID.  I asked if the dates are unique.

Comment: my bad. I read it as "data". Yes all dates are the same. all 50 records have the same purchase date.

Comment: Then you are getting a non-deterministic sort.  See my answer.

Comment: You also want to offset in multiples of 20.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If PurchaseDate is not unique then the order in that group is not guaranteed to repeat.
Add ID to the sort to get a repeatable sort.

```
SELECT * FROM Purchase WHERE dataOK = 'OK' 
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC, ID 
OFFSET  0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

SELECT * FROM Purchase WHERE dataOK = 'OK' 
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC, ID 
OFFSET 19 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

SELECT * FROM Purchase WHERE dataOK = 'OK' 
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC, ID 
OFFSET 39 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my life!

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows being returned is determined by the `FETCH` part of the command.  This is a *number of rows*.  It is not an offset position.

So, if you want 20 rows, then you will always have `FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY`.

The first two should not be returning the same results . . . although some results might look the same if you only look at `PurchaseDate`.

Answer (score 1):

@paparazzo has this figured out, but perhaps I can expand on their answer a bit.

An `ORDER BY PurchaseDate` clause will not be [deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017) if any two records in your table have the same `PurchaseDate`, because the ordering will still be satisfied regardless of which of those two records SQL Server elects to return first. In your case, since *all* of your records have the same `PurchaseDate`, SQL Server could return those records in *any order* and the clause would be satisfied. In other words, your `ORDER BY` clause is serving no purpose, save that you're required to have one in order to use `OFFSET...FETCH`.

Because you cannot know exactly what ordering will be produced by your `ORDER BY` clause, you also cannot know where a particular `OFFSET` will put you within that ordering, which means that you cannot know which records will be returned by *any* of your three queries. That SQL Server is returning the same result set for each of your first two queries is legal behavior, but even that is not guaranteed to happen every time; you could just as easily get different results.

If you need to guarantee that such queries will return disjoint sets, then you need to write your `ORDER BY` clause such that no two records have the same combination of values for the fields on which you're ordering. In your case, you say that you have a unique identifier for each row, so you could order first by `PurchaseDate` and then by that identifier, and your queries would work for you. Here's an example:

```
-- Create sample data: 50 records with unique RowNumber values and the same PurchaseDate value.
declare @Purchase table (RowNumber int, PurchaseDate date);
with Numbers as (select top 50 RowNumber = row_number() over (order by (select null)) from sys.objects)
insert @Purchase
select
    RowNumber,
    PurchaseDate = /*dateadd(day, RowNumber,*/ convert(date, getdate())/*)*/
from
    Numbers;

-- These result sets are nondeterministic because all the PurchaseDate values are the same, which
-- means that the records may be returned in any order and the ORDER BY will be satisfied.
select * from @Purchase order by PurchaseDate offset 0 rows fetch next 20 rows only;
select * from @Purchase order by PurchaseDate offset 20 rows fetch next 20 rows only;
select * from @Purchase order by PurchaseDate offset 40 rows fetch next 20 rows only;

-- Adding the unique RowNumber to my ORDER BY clause makes the results deterministic and therefore
-- guarantees that the following result sets will be rows 1-20, 21-40, and 41-50, respectively.
select * from @Purchase order by PurchaseDate, RowNumber offset 0 rows fetch next 20 rows only;
select * from @Purchase order by PurchaseDate, RowNumber offset 20 rows fetch next 20 rows only;
select * from @Purchase order by PurchaseDate, RowNumber offset 40 rows fetch next 20 rows only;
```

Note that if I were to uncomment the commented-out section of the line that assigns the `PurchaseDate` values, which would give each row a unique `PurchaseDate`, then I wouldn't need to include `RowNumber` in my `ORDER BY` clause in order to get disjoint sets, because `PurchaseDate` alone would be enough to guarantee a unique ordering.

Comment: I am cool, points don't really matter to me. I am not criticizing. Just a comment. If I expand on someone's answer I always +1 it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @paparazzo. I typically do the same, and add a comment rather than a new answer if I think something could use clarification. In this case I thought that your answer, while correct, was laconic enough that I wouldn't have understood it if I hadn't already known what was going on. But you _were_ the first one to arrive at what looks like the correct answer, and I see that you added a bit to it, so +1 for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write as

```
SELECT * 
FROM Purchase 
WHERE dataOK = 'OK' 
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
GO
SELECT * 
FROM Purchase 
WHERE dataOK = 'OK' 
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC OFFSET 19 ROWS FETCH NEXT 21 ROWS ONLY
SELECT * 
FROM Purchase 
WHERE dataOK = 'OK' 
ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC OFFSET 40 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```